# 2d circle rect collision and reflection doesnt work

Tags: algorithm, math, reflection, 2d, collision

I have game with map built by rectangles, darker rectangles (named "closed") mean its place where balls should be able to move, ball should reflect from the lighter rectangles(named "open") border. In future I'll add more balls and they will reflect from each other.

The problem is with new Vector after collision.

I force function circleRectGetCollisionNormal() to return vector(-1,0) what i think its normal for this case (ball is moving in right direction).
Ball is starting with degrees and change it simply to vector, this reflection worked for 45 degrees but when I change angle to 10 degrees ball moved into lighter rectangles(named "open").

[Here is how it looks like (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOlha.png)

I'm doing like this:

1-check if ball collided with lighter rectangle, 
2-if it collided, I want to change direction so I return vector, for example for right side of ball colliding with rectangle return [-1,0] (I think its normal of vertical line, and its pointing left direction).

3-calculate new ball move Vector from this equation: `newMoveVector = oldMoveVector − (2 * dotProduct(oldMoveVector, normalVector) * normalVector)`

Here is code for each step:

1.

```
   circleRect(circlePos, circleSize, rectPos, rectSize) { 
//its rectRect collision but it doesnt matter because reflection surface is always horizontal or vertical
        let r1 = {
            left: circlePos.x - circleSize.x/2,
            right: circlePos.x + circleSize.x/2,
            top: circlePos.y - circleSize.y/2,
            bottom: circlePos.y + circleSize.y/2
        };
        let r2 = {
            left: rectPos.x,
            right: rectPos.x + rectSize.x,
            top: rectPos.y,
            bottom: rectPos.y + rectSize.y
        };  
    return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
        r2.right < r1.left || 
        r2.top > r1.bottom ||
        r2.bottom < r1.top);
    }

    isOnOpenTile(pos: Vector, size: Vector) {
        let openTiles = this.getTiles('open');
        let result = false;
        openTiles.forEach(element => {
            if( this.circleRect(pos,size,element.pos,element.size) ){
                 result = element;
                return;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

2.

```
    circleRectGetCollisionNormal(c, r) {
        if(c.pos.y <= r.pos.y - (r.size.y/2)) return new Vector(0,-1);
        //Hit was from below the brick
        if(c.pos.y >= r.pos.y + (r.size.y/2)) return new Vector(0,1);
        //Hit was from above the brick
        if(c.pos.x < r.pos.x) return new Vector(1,0);
        //Hit was on left
        if(c.pos.x > r.pos.x) return new Vector(-1,0);
        //Hit was on right
        return false;
    }
```

3.

```
    getNewMoveVector(moveVector, normalVector) {
        normalVector = this.normalize(normalVector);
        let dot = (moveVector.x * moveVector.y) + (normalVector.x * normalVector.y);
        let dotProduct = new Vector(dot, dot);
        return moveVector.sub(dotProduct.mult(normalVector).mult(new Vector(2,2)));
    }

    normalize(v) {
        let length = Math.sqrt((v.x*v.x) + (v.y*v.y));
        return new Vector(v.x/length,v.y/length);
    }
```

And here is main function for this

```
        getMoveVectorOnCollision(circle) {
        let coll = this.isOnOpenTile( circle.pos, circle.size );
        if( coll != false) {
            let vector = this.circleRectGetCollisionNormal(circle, coll);
            return this.getNewMoveVector(circle.moveVector, vector);
        } else return false;
    }
```

Object Vector always contain 2 values all of function (mult, sub, div, add) work like here.

```
sub(vector: Vector) {
    return new Vector(this.x - vector.x, this.y - vector.y);
}
```

Please give me advice, actual solution or tell about different way to do this reflection. I wasted  more than 3 days trying to solve this, I have to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Yor dot product calculation is erroneous. Change these lines:

```
let dot = (moveVector.x * moveVector.y) + (normalVector.x * normalVector.y);
let dotProduct = new Vector(dot, dot);
```

by this one line:

```
let dotProduct = (moveVector.x * normalVector.x  + moveVector.y * normalVector.y);
```

Note that  `dotProduct` is **scalar value**, not vector, so you have to make vector for subtraction as

```
subvec.x = 2 * dotProduct * normalVector.x
subvec.y = 2 * dotProduct * normalVector.y
```

and

```
return moveVector.sub(subvec);
```

Comment: I will try your solution tommorow. I wrote sketch to figure this out by my own and I have something like this.  https://imgur.com/a/tivy6Rd
I generate two normals one for each side of line, when wrong normal is used ball is moving to wrong direction(like in the picture) , how can i check which one should be used? Sometimes first one is correct sometimes second one.
    function makeNormalsOfLine(line) {
    let dx = line.pos2.x-line.pos1.x;
    let dy = line.pos2.y-line.pos1.y;
    return [{x: -dy,y: dx},{x: dy, y: -dx}];
}

Comment: Your solution work, but only for vertical reflection. When ball touch bottom it start to move down and start shaking (server is generating new vector all the time).

Comment: Solution does not depend on wall, but you should provide correct normal direction. If vertices are numerated conterclockwise, internal normal is left one `{x: -dy,y: dx}`

Comment: Ok, now its often reflect circle good way, but sometimes collision is not detected correctly and slowly dive in to lighter area. Its because circle detect collision on top or bot rect border before left or right. How should i detect this collision?
Another problem is when circle touch bottom border of darker area, it dive a little reflect on bot border of rectangle (should reflect on top border) and go back. I think its because of collision but im not sure.

Comment: Perhaps your game loop is not made properly. Instead of checking for collision every time moment, it is better to find - what collision will happen first